# Aggregate $group returns wrong values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named **donation**

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "reqAmt" : 20,
    "filled" : [
        {
            userId : 1,
            depAmt : 5
        }
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : 2,
    "reqAmt" : 20,
    "filled" : []
},
```

Expected result

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "reqAmt" : 20,
    "filledAmt" : 5
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "reqAmt" : 20,
    "filledAmt" : 0
}
```

I tried with **$unwind** .but no luck. It always returns

```
{ "_id" : null, "filledAmt" : 0 }
```

Below are the codes

```
db.donation.aggregate([{$unwind:"$filled"},{$project:{"reqAmt":1,"filledAmt":1} },{$group:{"_id":null,"filledAmt":{"$sum":"$filled.depAmt"}}}])
```

Comment: Try `{$project:{"reqAmt":1,"filled":1}`

Comment: Hi @veeram, I already tried. But same result :(